# Is silverlight scalable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, silverlight-4.0

Is silverlight more scalable then HTML. I found out that silverlight code runs on the client except whrn it has to update or fetch data from the server. Will my application be more responsive if I develop it in silverlight. I am not worried about end users installing silverlight on the clients. I am in a position to install silverlight on clients myself.

i just need to know if I develop a silverlight application will it make my application more scalable and/or responsive

Comment: More scalable and responsive than what? HTML, WinForms, C++? Your question isn't complete

Comment: What do you mean by scalable? Are you planning on doing some kind of grid/cluster computing? Do you need the client to use multiple cores? Multiple CPUs? Multiple physical machines? Scalable in which way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight applications are, for all intents and purposes, "fat client" applications delivered over the web.  Their code is executed on the local machine, and communication with a data store is conducted over WCF web services, which are usually wrapped by RIA Services.

Silverlight applications are quite responsive once loaded.  Building a well-performing UI in Silverlight may be a little more challenging than it would be in WPF, but not by much.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't make sense. HTML by itself doesn't *do* anything. There is no interactivity, nothing that can *be* responsive.

Of course, web apps typically rely on server-side logic (which requires a network round-trip, causing a delay) and Javascript (which runs locally, and so is pretty snappy)... But HTML itself is just a language for describing documents. It doesn't *do* anything, and it isn't "responsive" or "scalable".

Ultimately, it's much the same either way: it won't make a noticeable difference in terms of responsiveness whether you implement your logic in Javascript on a HTML page or in Silverlight. And when you need to communicate with the server, it doesn't matter if the browser or the Silverlight plugin makes the request, in both cases it requires a network round-trip.

Comment: +1  The biggest key is that the "html" app logic must be in JAVASCRIPT, not code server side code behind with postbacks and what not.  An app like that is incredible slow by modern standards.

Comment: Of course everyone knows if a web application is all html there will be more full round trips to the server. If facebook was 100% silverlight do you think they would need so many servers and bandwidth then they have now?

Comment: @Luke: Yes. They'd still have to do the same amount of server-side processing. How would you 'like' something without a round-trip to the server? How would you read your friends' status lines? That data doesn't magically appear on the client, whether or not you're using Silverlight. It has to be requested by the client (a browser or Silverlight), and then sent from the server. The technology used to write the client makes little difference there.

Comment: Also I'm not sure how much "everyone knows", but your question was very unclear. And please don't downvote answers just because they don't tell you what you *want* to hear. Downvote if the answer is incorrect. If you get a lot of bad answers, perhaps the problem is your *question*.

Comment: @jalf: I see. Your answer now conflicts with Dave answer. Are you saying that performance will not change if an application is written in silverlight? Dave says it will be more responsive and code will run on the client. Do you disagree with Dave? If code is ran on the client wouldn't that make the application more scalable since it is not running on the server? If silverlight requests information is it requesting more information versus a dynamic html web application?

Comment: Also, My colleages have mentioned that ajax can help web application be more scalable but not by much. Is this true? If so, I dont see any need for silverlight since the database will always be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Scalable in terms of what? Bandwidth, server CPU?

In theory moving the processing to the client will help server CPU but your data  requests will still need processing. Also if you silverlight app is bigger than the web page(s) it would replace you may end up with more bandwidth being used. (You could use a CDN though)

In principle though if many pages are hit during one session it would be fair to think it could be more scalable.

Other issues such as market reachable come into play of course but having a client side app is an approach I have used to help speed and costs.

Comment: Scalable in terms of what? Bandwidth, server CPU? Both!

Comment: Upvoted to counter spurious downvotes. Please don't downvote unless you have a valid reason, and if so, post a comment *describing* that reason. And "I wanted another answer to my question" is not a valid reason. It just means you should put more effort into *asking* your question.